# How Would I Pronounce (In Topology), Dual of V* Operations Descriptions

Tags: general-topology

I am looking at operations for addition and scalar multiplication while reading about the dual of a vector space. Symbols are chained together in long lines (which is what makes this much more difficult to know how to pronounce), and I am wondering *how I would read these aloud*?

LaTeX of the operations seems to be described by what follows, but I will add PNG images too:

$$a\underset{\rightarrow}{v} : \mathsf{V} \rightarrow \mathsf{K}\ \ :\ \ \vec{x} \mapsto (a\underset{\rightarrow}{v})[\overset{\rightarrow}{x}] := a(\underset{\rightarrow}{v}[\vec{x}])$$

$$\underset{\rightarrow}{v} + \underset{\rightarrow}{w} : \mathsf{V} \rightarrow \mathsf{K}\ \ :\ \ \vec{x} \mapsto (\underset{\rightarrow}{v} + \underset{\rightarrow}{w})[\vec{x}] := \underset{\rightarrow}v[\vec{x}] + \underset{\rightarrow}w[\vec{x}]$$

[image: PNG, Dual of V, Addition]

[image: PNG, Dual of V, Multiplication]

Comment: Sorry, had to correct this, my LaTeX was wrong. Also found out how to see in LaTeX view :)